# How do I get output as 0 instead of nothing with empty entry value

Tags: javascript, html

I need a help figuring out how to make javascript output a 0 as a value instead of nothing. If there is no value given it does not output 0.

```
        Util.ogl.shipsList.forEach(shipID =>
        {
            jsonData[0][0].lifeformBonuses.BaseStatsBooster[shipID] = jsonData[0][0].lifeformBonuses.BaseStatsBooster[shipID] || {};

            Object.entries(Util.ogl.db.lfBonuses?.[shipID] || {}).forEach(entry =>
            {
                if(entry[0] == 'fuel' && entry[1] != 0) jsonData[0][0].lifeformBonuses.ShipFuelConsumption = Math.abs(entry[1] / 100);
                else jsonData[0][0].lifeformBonuses.BaseStatsBooster[shipID][entry[0]] = entry[1] / 100;
            });
        });
```

This is the piece of code that is giving me the trouble

This is what it looks like:

[image: This is what it looks like]

And this is what I need it to be like

[image: And this is what I need it to be like]

I tried editing the code by adding additional if statements with the different fields, however I am no good at javascript so no luck there, also I tried making all the values be 0 but that was of no help as some need to have their values like this:

[image: Like this]

Comment: What do you mean by "output", and what do you mean by "nothing"?

Comment: I don't see any way that `entry[1] / 100` can return an empty string. Even if `entry[1]` is an empty string, `/` will convert it to a number `0` and the division will return `0`.

Comment: I mean the output in the table, if you check the pictures you will see, in certain fields it works normally and outputs 0 in them, but in all others it does not fill anything

Comment: You haven't posted any code that creates an HTML table or dropdowns. You're just setting `jsonData` values, we can't see how they get put into the HTML.

Comment: Barmar it is due to that as you mentioned, I did some digging around with a friend and we found out that it is due to that basically. The whole thing works by checking if there was any change from the base stasts and if there was it creates the table, but if a certain ID did not have any change it does not get created which results in the empty table, since each row is set to match with a corresponding ID, is there any easier way to just make the code put 0 into all empty fields that weren't filled by the piece of code I have posted here?